# postfix relay SMTP oulook.com

Tags: email, postfix, mail, smtp

I have a *Ubuntu 14.04.5*, and I'm trying to config the `postfix` relay an external *SMTP* with *[smtp-mail.outlook.com]:587*.

I tried to search online and did some changes, but it still not working.
Here are the details:

This is the error from `webmin` interface look like:

```
Failed to send mail : SMTP command mail from: <root@ubuntu> failed : 530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM [AM5PR0201CA0008.eurprd02.prod.outlook.com]
```